# Are で and に particles interchangeable when using them with 乗ります and 降ります verbs?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, english-to-japanese, particle-を

I'm reading a book that translates these two sentences as following:

1. スミスさんは東京駅で電車**に**乗ります。-> Mr. Smith will get on the train at Tokyo Station.
2. スミスさんは新宿駅で電車**を**降ります。-> Mr. Smith will get off the train at Shinjuku Station.

As you can see, the first sentence uses に before the verb and the second one uses を.　I don't understand why this happens. **Could you explain it?**

Are these two particles interchangeable in this situation, that is, could I use を in the first sentence and に in the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not interchangeable in this circumstance. In general, boarding a vehicle takes the particle に with 乗る. Getting off a vehicle often takes the particle を to mark the object of the action of getting off.

As a memory trick (if it helps), think of getting on something as movement upwards (stepping up onto a train, getting up on a bike, climbing on a horse, etc.), and associate that movement with the particle に. When you are getting off (getting down), think of the vehicle as the object of the verb (get off [object]), and associate that with を. It's not technically accurate but it might help to conceptualize it in this way.